Cannot connect my Node.js Backend Server to MongoDB on Vercel
I have a React/Node.js project where I am deploying only the backend (server folder) to Vercel. The backend is hosted correctly on Vercel, and I can confirm this with a simple API test I made in server.js:
$ curl https://<mylink>/api/test
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    29  100    29    0     0    149      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   151
{"message":"API is working!"}


However, when I try to make any requests that interact with my MongoDB database, it fails with the following response:
$ curl https://<mylink>/api/db-debug
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    85  100    85    0     0    432      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   435
{"message":"Database debug error","error":"Connection not established: Disconnected"}


I've followed all the steps to integrate my Vercel deployment with MongoDB Atlas:
User Access: I created a user vercel-admin-user with the role readWriteAnyDatabase@admin.
IP Whitelisting: I've added 0.0.0.0/0 to the Network Access whitelist in MongoDB Atlas to allow connections from any IP.
Environment Variable: My MONGO_URI is set correctly in the Vercel environment variables.
The API works perfectly locally:
$ curl http://localhost:5000/api/db-test
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    75  100    75    0     0   2277      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2343
{"message":"The MONGODB Database connection is working!","result":{"ok":1}}


Vercel Logs:
When I call the /api/db-test endpoint from the deployed backend, I get the following error in the Vercel logs:
Database connection error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'admin')
    at /var/task/server/server.js:121:49
    ...
Error connecting to MongoDB: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/


Here is the code for the /api/db-test endpoint:
app.get('/api/db-test', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await mongoose.connection.db.admin().ping();
    res.json({ message: 'The MONGODB Database connection is working!', result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Database connection error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Database connection error', error });
  }
});


